# Pass data from one view to another view, using target

Tags: sapui5

I am new to sapui5, i am trying to make an app with two views.one view with multicomboBox and another with dynamic table , after selection of items from multicomboBox i have to click submit button. on submit button click i have to navigate to another view and create a table with column name, column name will be selected values of multicomboBox.
i am using target to navigate and used xml view.
The problem is i am getting the selected items, how to pass the selected data to another view and create the table  is the issue i am facing.
i am posting the views and controllers below. The below code is taken from sapui5 Explored, i have combined multicomboBox and Target Program. Thanks in advance

**View1.xml**

```
<mvc:View 
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    controllerName="sap.ui.core.sample.trial.targetsApp.controller.View1" 
    xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form">
     <App>  
        <Page title="Example 1">  
            <MultiComboBox selectionChange="handleSelectionChange" selectionFinish="handleSelectionFinish" width="500px"
  items="{
                    path: '/Collection',
                     sorter: { path: 'Name' }
                }">
  <core:Item key="{ProductId}" text="{Name}" />
  </MultiComboBox>
  <footer>  
                <Bar>  
                    <contentRight>  
                        <Button text="Submit" press="onToView2" />  
                    </contentRight>  
                </Bar>  
            </footer>  

        </Page>  
    </App>  
 </mvc:View>
```

**View2.xml**

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    controllerName="sap.ui.core.sample.trial.targetsApp.controller.View2" 
    xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form">
     <App>  
        <Page title="TableView"
  showNavButton="true"
  navButtonPress="onBack"> 
  <footer>  
                <Bar>  
                    <contentRight>  
                        <Button text="Submit" press="onToView2" />  
                    </contentRight>  
                </Bar>  
            </footer>  

        </Page>  
    </App>  
 </mvc:View>
```

**controller for view1**

```
sap.ui.define([
        'jquery.sap.global',
        'sap/m/MessageToast',
        'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
        'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
        ], function(jQuery, MessageToast, Controller, JSONModel) {
        "use strict";


        var PageController = Controller.extend("sap.ui.core.sample.trial.targetsApp.controller.View1", {


        onInit: function () {
        // set explored app's demo model on this sample
        var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap.ui.demo.mock", "/products.json"));
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
        },


        onToView2 : function () {

        this.getOwnerComponent().getTargets().display("page2");
    },

        handleSelectionChange: function(oEvent) {
        var changedItem = oEvent.getParameter("changedItem");
        var isSelected = oEvent.getParameter("selected");


        var state = "Selected";
        if (!isSelected) {
        state = "Deselected"
        }


        MessageToast.show("Event 'selectionChange': " + state + " '" + changedItem.getText() + "'", {
        width: "auto"
        });
        },


        handleSelectionFinish: function(oEvent) {
        var selectedItems = oEvent.getParameter("selectedItems");
        var messageText = "Event 'selectionFinished': [";


        for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        messageText += "'" + selectedItems[i].getText() + "'";
        if (i != selectedItems.length-1) {
        messageText += ",";
        }
        }


        messageText += "]";


        MessageToast.show(messageText, {
        width: "auto"
        });
        },

        handleNav: function(evt){
        this.getOwnerComponent().getTargets().display("page2");
        }
        });




        return PageController;


       }, true);
```

**controller for view2**

```
sap.ui.define( ["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"], function (Controller) {
  "use strict";


  return Controller.extend("sap.ui.core.sample.trial.targetsApp.controller.View2", {
  onBack : function () {
  this.getOwnerComponent().getTargets().display("page1");
  }
  });


},true);
```

**Edited controller2.js**

```
sap.ui.define( ["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.core.sample.trial.targetsApp.controller.View2", {

        onInit:function(){
              //console.log(sap.ui.getCore().AppContext.selectedArray);

              //console.log(sap.ui.getCore().AppContext.selectedArray.length);

              var oTable = new sap.m.Table();
              for(var i = 0;i < sap.ui.getCore().AppContext.selectedArray.length;i++){
              oTable.addColumn(new sap.m.Column({
                  demandPopin : true,
                  header:new sap.m.Text({text:sap.ui.getCore().AppContext.selectedArray[i]})
              }));
              }
              //not working i want to place it in view2.xml
              //oTable.placeAt("content");

        },
        displayPress : function(){

             console.log(sap.ui.getCore().AppContext.selectedArray);

              console.log(sap.ui.getCore().AppContext.selectedArray.length);
              console.log(sap.ui.getCore().AppContext.selectedArray[0]);
              console.log(sap.ui.getCore().AppContext.selectedArray[1]);

        },
        onBack : function () {
            this.getOwnerComponent().getTargets().display("page1");
        }
    });

}, true);
```

**edited view2.xml**

```
<mvc:View
           xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
           xmlns="sap.m"
           xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
           xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
           controllerName="sap.ui.core.sample.trial.targetsApp.controller.View2" 
           xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form">
     <App>  
        <Page title="TableView"
            showNavButton="true"
            navButtonPress="onBack"> 
             <l:HorizontalLayout id="tableid">

             </l:HorizontalLayout>    

            <footer>  
                <Bar>  
                    <contentRight>  
                        <Button text="Add New Rows" press="displayPress" />  
                        <Button text="display" press="displayPress" /> 
                    </contentRight>  
                </Bar>  
            </footer>  

        </Page>  
    </App>  
 </mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in `handleNav` function:

```
//yourData can be any variable or object
this.getOwnerComponent().getTargets().display("page2", yourData);
```

Read more here:

display(vTargets, vData?): [sap.ui.core.routing.Targets](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Targets.html#display)

Comment: i got the data using sap.ui.getCore().AppContext = new Object();

Comment: how to create a table if i have array for ex. myarray["a","b"]; i want to create sap.m.table with columns a and b

Comment: you want with sap.m.Table? or sap.ui.table.Table?

Comment: i want to place table in my second view.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: i tried to give id to horizontal layout and place it in that, but no luck.. i even tried to place it in html body still not working.

Comment: I believe you are writing XML code in view. Can you please add your changes or create new message..

Comment: in above code i have just added horizontalLayout in the view2.xml

Comment: You need 10 points I guess.. It's ok. You got help that is more important

Comment: I cant see the method in the API docs you refernce also I can't see how you can access the data (in the second argument) in the target view. Can you clarify this?

Comment: This is for passing the parameters, but how do I read them in the other controller?